# Show all ids that has id under a specific number

Tags: jquery

Im doing a script where it shows different equal of divs on select.

```
    <select name="amount" id="amount" >
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    </select>
    <div class="class" id="1">test</div>
    <div class="class" id="2">test2</div>
    <div class="class" id="3">test3</div>
    <div class="class" id="4">test4</div>
    <div class="class" id="5">test5</div>
    <div class="class" id="6">test6</div>
    <div class="class" id="7">test7</div>
    <div class="class" id="8">test8</div>
    <input type="submit" id="buttong" name="submit" class="rounded" value="Random" style="margin-left: 10px;">
</form>
<script>

$("select").change(
function()
{
$(".class").hide();
$(".class[id='"+this.value+"']").show();
})

</script>
```

How do i change:

```
$("select").change(
function()
{
$(".class").hide();
$(".class[id='"+this.value+"']").show();
})
```

So it will show all div that has the id number under the selected.

So for example if i select number 5, it will show all divs that has lower number, 1 2 3 4 5

Now it only show the number i selected.

Comment: style suggestion: try to add a transition: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp to the div, so they will gracefully fade instead of brutal pop, like `all 400ms ease`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select").on('change', function () {
    var chosen_nr = this.value + 1;
    $(".class").hide();
    $(".class").each(function() {
        if (this.id < chosen_nr ) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

I gave a variable `chosen_nr` the value of the `select` and added +1 because the jQuery array starts on `0`. Then I made a `each` loop and run `.show()` on all divs which `id` was less than `chosen_nr`.

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NnBbV/2/)**

Comment: @user2705154, great! glad I could help! Please click to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#amount').change(function(){
    $('#amount').attr('disabled');
    var num=$(this).val();
    $('.class').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id')>num)
            $(this).css('display','none');
        else
            $(this).css('display','block');
    });
    $('#amount').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function()
{
    currentID = $(this).val();
    $(".class").hide().each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("id") <= currentID)
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use IDs for that case, use indexes:

```
$("select").change(function() {
   var index = $(this).prop("selectedIndex");
   $('.class').hide().filter(':lt(' + index + ')').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does seem like something that would be trivial without a library ?

```
document.getElementById('amount').onchange = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<this.options.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(i+1).style.display = i<this.value ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MJGV7/)